# Capybara::ElementNotFound - Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, rspec3

this has been driving me crazy. Please help, I'm sure it's a simple fix, even though it's for a silly treehouse todo app. (So those of you experienced programmers on your lunchbreak please help me out, I wouldn't resort to this if it was needed).

I'm trying to create an authentication system, and I'm getting failures for not being able to find css"#todo_list_1"

This is all after I run BIN/RAKE

Here's a list of my failures:

Failures:

```
1) Editing todo items is successful with valid content
 Failure/Error: visit_todo_list(todo_list)
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find css "#todo_list_1"
 # ./spec/support/todo_list_helpers.rb:4:in `visit_todo_list'
 # ./spec/features/todo_items/edit_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) Editing todo items is unsuccessful with not enough content
 Failure/Error: visit_todo_list(todo_list)
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find css "#todo_list_1"
 # ./spec/support/todo_list_helpers.rb:4:in `visit_todo_list'
 # ./spec/features/todo_items/edit_spec.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

3) Editing todo items is unsuccessful with no content
 Failure/Error: visit_todo_list(todo_list)
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find css "#todo_list_1"
 # ./spec/support/todo_list_helpers.rb:4:in `visit_todo_list'
 # ./spec/features/todo_items/edit_spec.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

4) Editing todo lists updates a todo list successfully with correct information
 Failure/Error: within "#todo_list_#{todo_list.id}" do
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find css "#todo_list_1"
 # ./spec/features/todo_lists/edit_spec.rb:14:in `update_todo_list'
 # ./spec/features/todo_lists/edit_spec.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

5) Editing todo lists displays an error with too short a title
 Failure/Error: within "#todo_list_#{todo_list.id}" do
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find css "#todo_list_1"
 # ./spec/features/todo_lists/edit_spec.rb:14:in `update_todo_list'
 # ./spec/features/todo_lists/edit_spec.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

6) Editing todo lists displays an error with no title
 Failure/Error: within "#todo_list_#{todo_list.id}" do
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find css "#todo_list_1"
 # ./spec/features/todo_lists/edit_spec.rb:14:in `update_todo_list'
 # ./spec/features/todo_lists/edit_spec.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

7) Editing todo lists displays an error with no description
 Failure/Error: within "#todo_list_#{todo_list.id}" do
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find css "#todo_list_1"
 # ./spec/features/todo_lists/edit_spec.rb:14:in `update_todo_list'
 # ./spec/features/todo_lists/edit_spec.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

8) Editing todo lists displays an error with no title
 Failure/Error: within "#todo_list_#{todo_list.id}" do
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find css "#todo_list_1"
 # ./spec/features/todo_lists/edit_spec.rb:14:in `update_todo_list'
 # ./spec/features/todo_lists/edit_spec.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

9) Deleting todo lists is successful when clicking the destroy link
 Failure/Error: within "#todo_list_#{todo_list.id}" do
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find css "#todo_list_1"
 # ./spec/features/todo_lists/destroy_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

10) todo_lists/index renders a list of todo_lists
 Failure/Error: assert_select "tr>td", :text => "Title".to_s, :count => 2
 Minitest::Assertion:
   Expected exactly 2 elements matching "tr > td", found 0..
   Expected: 2
     Actual: 0
 # ./spec/views/todo_lists/index.html.erb_spec.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

11) Completing todo items is successful when marking a single item complete
 Failure/Error: visit_todo_list todo_list
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find css "#todo_list_1"
 # ./spec/support/todo_list_helpers.rb:4:in `visit_todo_list'
 # ./spec/features/todo_items/complete_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

12) Completing todo items with completed items shows completed items as complete
 Failure/Error: visit_todo_list todo_list
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find css "#todo_list_1"
 # ./spec/support/todo_list_helpers.rb:4:in `visit_todo_list'
 # ./spec/features/todo_items/complete_spec.rb:21:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

13) Completing todo items with completed items does not give the option to make complete
 Failure/Error: visit_todo_list todo_list
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find css "#todo_list_1"
 # ./spec/support/todo_list_helpers.rb:4:in `visit_todo_list'
 # ./spec/features/todo_items/complete_spec.rb:28:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

14) Viewing todo items displays the title of the todo list
 Failure/Error: visit_todo_list(todo_list)
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find css "#todo_list_1"
 # ./spec/support/todo_list_helpers.rb:4:in `visit_todo_list'
 # ./spec/features/todo_items/index_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

15) Viewing todo items displays item content when a todo list has items
 Failure/Error: visit_todo_list(todo_list)
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find css "#todo_list_1"
 # ./spec/support/todo_list_helpers.rb:4:in `visit_todo_list'
 # ./spec/features/todo_items/index_spec.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

16) Viewing todo items displays no items when a todo list is empty
 Failure/Error: visit_todo_list(todo_list)
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find css "#todo_list_1"
 # ./spec/support/todo_list_helpers.rb:4:in `visit_todo_list'
 # ./spec/features/todo_items/index_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

17) Adding todo items is successful with valid content
 Failure/Error: visit_todo_list(todo_list)
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find css "#todo_list_1"
 # ./spec/support/todo_list_helpers.rb:4:in `visit_todo_list'
 # ./spec/features/todo_items/create_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

18) Adding todo items displays an error with content les than 2 characters long
 Failure/Error: visit_todo_list(todo_list)
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find css "#todo_list_1"
 # ./spec/support/todo_list_helpers.rb:4:in `visit_todo_list'
 # ./spec/features/todo_items/create_spec.rb:31:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

19) Adding todo items displays an error with no content
 Failure/Error: visit_todo_list(todo_list)
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find css "#todo_list_1"
 # ./spec/support/todo_list_helpers.rb:4:in `visit_todo_list'
 # ./spec/features/todo_items/create_spec.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

20) Deleting todo items is successful
 Failure/Error: visit_todo_list(todo_list)
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find css "#todo_list_1"
 # ./spec/support/todo_list_helpers.rb:4:in `visit_todo_list'
 # ./spec/features/todo_items/delete_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here's a list of my ./spec/support/todo_list_helpers.rb:4

```
module TodoListHelpers
def visit_todo_list(list)
    visit "/todo_lists"
    within dom_id_for(list) do
        click_link "List Items"
    end
  end
end
```

Here's a list of my ./spec/views/todo_lists/index.html.erb_spec

require 'spec_helper'

```
describe "Deleting todo lists" do
    let!(:todo_list) { TodoList.create(title: "Groceries", description: "Grocery list.") }

    it "is successful when clicking the destroy link" do
        visit "/todo_lists"

        within "#todo_list_#{todo_list.id}" do
            click_link "Destroy"
        end
        expect(page).to_not have_content(todo_list.title)
        expect(TodoList.count).to eq(0)
        end
    end
```

Here's a list of my ./spec/views/todo_lists/index.html.erb_spec

require 'spec_helper'

```
describe "todo_lists/index" do
  before(:each) do
    assign(:todo_lists, [
      stub_model(TodoList,
        :title => "Title",
        :description => "MyText"
  ),
  stub_model(TodoList,
    :title => "Title",
    :description => "MyText"
  )
])
  end

  it "renders a list of todo_lists" do
    render
    # Run the generator again with the --webrat flag if you want to use webrat matchers
    assert_select "tr>td", :text => "Title".to_s, :count => 2
    assert_select "tr>td", :text => "MyText".to_s, :count => 2
   end
 end
```

***Here's my app/views/todo_lists/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Todo Lists</h1>


<% @todo_lists.each do |todo_list| %>
<div class="todo_list" id"<%= dom_id(todo_list) %>">
    <h2><%= todo_list.title %></h2>
    <p><%= todo_list.description %></p>
    <ul class="functions">
        <li><%= link_to "List Items", todo_list_todo_items_path(todo_list) %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Show', todo_list %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_todo_list_path(todo_list) %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Destroy', todo_list, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></li>
    </ul>

    <br class="clear" />
 </div>
  <% end %>

 <br>

 <%= link_to 'New Todo list', new_todo_list_path %>
```

Comment: Thanks for all this code but the issue has to do with your `#index` view which we cannot see.

Comment: Hey engineersmnky thanks so much for the quick response. 

I added the index for you to see. Hopefully that helps. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Forgot an = after id

I had

```
id"<%= dom_id
```

It needed to be

```
id="<%= dom_id
```